# any reference to the code that calculating time difference similar to stackoverflow?

Tags: php, datetime

Does anybody has any reference to the code in PHP that calculating time difference similar to stackoverflow?

for example:
given a time stamp '2011-08-03 07:15:22', produce less than a minute ago,
given a time stamp '2011-08-02 15:28:33', produce Yesterday at 15:28:33 ,
something like this,

appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at http://timeago.yarp.com/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, this is nice. I would prefer that if there is anything in php.

Comment: It will be better if you do this on client side rather than server side. but if you still want to do it in php have at look at http://www.phpsnippets.info/display-dates-as-time-ago

Comment: ok, could be please explain the advantage of doing this in client side?

Comment: 1 - Avoid timestamps dated "1 minute ago" even though the page was opened 10 minutes ago; timeago refreshes automatically.
2 - You can take full advantage of page caching in your web applications, because the timestamps aren't calculated on the server.

Comment: Client-side means they can update - if you load Facebook and let it sit for a while, you'll see the "just now" change to "2 minutes ago" etc.

Answer (score 1):

These are generally called "fuzzy time" displays.

There are a lot of pre-built functions, like [this one](http://blog.slapthink.net/2009/04/16/fuzzy-time-or-relative-time-in-php/), but the general logic is that you can compare the date with the current date and get the difference, and display different responses based on how large that difference is.

Comment: haha, I was really thinking what term would that be, fuzzy time :)
,this is a good reference. thanks.

Comment: It's one of those programming concepts that once you have the magic words you find a million results, but trying to find those magic words is really hard. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Rails, you can use time_ago_in_words

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(question.created_at) %>
```

Details here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words

Comment: This example is exactly what I am looking for, but in php :)